# How to Deserialize "Serialized Protobuffer" in c++ which is generated using C# protobuf-net

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have a struct

```
[ProtoContract]
    public struct TenprintTemplateStructure
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public byte[] FeatureTenprint { get; set; } //Tenpritn NTemplate's NBuffer

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public int TemplateID { get; set; } //Template ID

        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public long TemplateSize { get; set; } //Template Size

        [ProtoMember(4)]
        public string PersonID { get; set; } //Person ID

        [ProtoMember(5)]
        public int IsActive { get; set; } // Person's Status
    };
```

and I am serializing multiple instance of this struct to a file using c# proto-buf with length prefix Fixed32. code is below,(tenprintTemplateStruct is the struct im writing)

```
ProtoBuf.Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, tenprintTemplateStruct, ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle.Fixed32, 0);
```

I know it can be deserializeable using c++. i tried some solution but did not succeeded yet.

have anyone done this before?

Comment: btw; side question: why is that a `struct`? Every bone and sinew in my body is screaming `class` when looking at that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the C++ side, you have 4 steps to perform:

- generate the C++ code using the `protoc` tool; you can either write a .proto schema manually, or you use `string proto = Serializer.GetProto<TenprintTemplateStructure>();` (from your .NET code) as a starting point
- read exactly 4 bytes from the input and parse it as a 32-bit integer; `Fixed32` is documented as little-endian, so: do that
- wrap you actual stream with a length-limited stream of this length; google provide [LimitingInputStream](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.zero_copy_stream_impl#LimitingInputStream) for this
- follow the [C++ guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial) for actually deserializing - primarily [ParseFromIstream](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message)

Comment: Here is my code: uint32 ByteSize = 0;
  while (coded_input->ReadVarint32(&ByteSize))
  {
   CodedInputStream::Limit codedLimit = coded_input->PushLimit(ByteSize);
   TemplateData.ParseFromCodedStream(coded_input);
   coded_input->PopLimit(codedLimit);

   FingerPrintNode* pFingerPrintNode = new FingerPrintNode;
   this->translateFromProtoBuffToFingerPrintNode(&TemplateData, pFingerPrintNode);
   this->AddToCache(pFingerPrintNode);
  }

Comment: Should i use ReadVarint32(&ByteSize) or ReadLittleEndian32(&ByteSize) in the while loop?? is there any difference??

Comment: `ReadVarint32` reads a *varint*; very different to a fixed 32-bit number. If you store with `Fixed32`, then yes `ReadLittleEndian32` sounds the right approach, and yes there is a *huge* difference between them.

Comment: My question is, if i want to read Length prefix using "ReadVarient32()" in c++ side. should i have to write Length prefix using "ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian" in c# side? or is there exist any othere approach?

Comment: @Rezoan if you want to read with `ReadVarint32`, then write with the `PrefixStyle.Base128`. Same thing, basically. Perhaps badly named by me.